# Xcode storyboard interface not show any element

Tags: xcode, storyboard

my Xcode storyboard not showing any element my Mac is MacBook Air M1

I tried to delete driverData but doesn't work

[image]

Comment: Quit and restart.

Comment: it doesn't work I tried to remove the DriverData file doesn't work also

Comment: after I did use HD Cleaner then I restarted Xcode it works normally